# Passing Angular Components Into One Another

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular component that wraps content with some formatting (borders, header, footer, etc.) and I want to store not just basic primitive content like text, but also some other angular components. Some pseudo-code from the HTML perspective might look like.

```
<content-wrapper>
  Here's some text content to display
</content-wrapper>

<content-wrapper>
  Here's my great logo component with awesome CSS and on-hover capabilities.
  <my-great-logo></my-great-logo>
</content-wrapper>
```

Is it possible to do something like this? So far I've just been passing string content via @Input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
This feature is called `content projection`. Details: https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Just add `ng-content` element into your ContentWrapperComponent's template.

Component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'content-wrapper',
    templateUrl: './content-wrapper.component.html',
})
export class ContentWrapperComponent {
    @Input()
    text: string
}
```

Template:

```js
<h1>{{ text }}</h1>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Usage:

```js
<content-wrapper text="Main text">
    <h3>additional text</h3>
    <my-great-logo></my-great-logo>
</content-wrapper>
```